# accessing non-template base class virtual function from template derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm trying to understand the template and inheritance. I have a base class as follows:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void setId(u_int8_t id)
    {
        m_id = id;
    }

private:
    u_int8_t m_id;
};
```

and a derived template class as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class Data : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void setId(u_int8_t id)
    {
        this->setId(id);
    }

    inline void setData(const T& data)
    {
        m_data = data;
    }

    inline T& data()
    {
        return m_data;
    }

private:
    T m_data;
};
```

this code compiles fine but crashes at run time. Why is this happening?

Comment: Crashes at run time - stack overflow? Try also this: `void Foo(){Foo();}`

Comment: Does it have anything to do with templates?

Comment: @juanchopanza yes there are many types of data and I don't want to write it for all types of possible types.

Comment: OK, let me spell that out. Does the problem you are reporting have anything at all to do with templates?

Comment: it would be really nice to mention the reason for down vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a stack overflow because `setId` keeps calling itself. To call the `setId` in the base class, use

```
virtual void setId(u_int8_t id)
{
    Base::setId(id);
}
```

Comment: I thought using `this` would specify what function I like to call exactly.

Comment: also as stated [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html) _Change the call from f() to B<T>::f(). Note however that this might not give you what you want if f() is virtual, since it inhibits the virtual dispatch mechanism._

Comment: `this` refers to the current object, which is of type `Data`, so `Data::setID` is used. The parashift link talks about a different (visibility/name lookup) problem when a class template derives from another class template; you'll notice that `f()` and `g()` in the code there don't share the same name.

Comment: but what if I want to re-implement my base class virtual function in some template derived classes but use the default implementation in other template derived classes? wouldn't this create a problem as stated in that website?

Comment: No. All this does it call `Base::setID` in `Data::setID`. If `Data::setID` is not called, this line is not executed, and nothing changes for anything else. What the parashift article means is a situation in which a class template derives from another class template, something else derives from *that* class template and overloads a virtual function from the base class template, and if then you have a function in the middle class template that wants to call the virtual function from the base. I think in that case you'd want to say `use Base::setID` in the middle class template.

Comment: OK! thanks. Now to clarify my doubts could you please explain what that website is exactly talking about?

Answer (score 1):

This function:

```
virtual void setId(u_int8_t id)
{
    this->setId(id);
}
```

It is calling itself recursively, until the process runs out of stack space and you get a crash.

To call a function from the base-class you have to use the scope operator:

```
Base::setId(id);
```

Comment: why is it calling itself? I thought calling `this` will specify that the method should call the `Base` class `setId()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `setId()` function recursively calls itself forever.  You want:

```
virtual void setId(u_int8_t id)
{
     Base::setId(Id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need `setId(u_int8_t id)` in `Data`. The method is inherited from `Base`.
If you are intending to provide a different implementation in derived class, and use in this different implementation the implementation of the `Base`, then use `Base::setId(id)` (as Joachim Pileborg pointed out)

P.S.: Actually, there is nothing specific to templates in your question.

Comment: upvote for reminding of the Inheritance, but I would like to understand the reason this doesn't work in contrast to inheriting from a template base class.